# Error is "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.marter.travel.model.Picture]"

Tags: spring, mongodb

The error facing now is "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.marter.travel.model.Picture]"

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document (collection = "tourpackage")

public class TourPackage {

    private ArrayList<Picture> picture;

    public ArrayList<Picture> getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(ArrayList<Picture> picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring Data and `Picture` is another class mapped with `@Document`.
You must add `@DBRef` annotation on `ArrayList<Picture>`

```
@DBRef
private ArrayList<Picture> picture;
```