# Error mapping JPA custom-query to my DTO model

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I've created a custom `query` that returns data from different tables in a new table. However `JPA` is not able to map the result to my `DTO` object.

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [model.myModel]
```

This is my model class

```
@Data
public class myModel {

    private String name;
    
    private Integer id;
}
```

and my Repository with the `custom query`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT name, id_tr AS id FROM (SELECT A.nombre name, D.id_transaccion from tableA A LEFT JOIN ....  RESULTED WHERE RESULTED.id_tr IN (?1)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<myModel> findNameOperation(List<Integer> idList);
```

What is the problem? I have named the attributes of my `DTO` in the same way as the fields that would come out in my table.
I read this article [Error is "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.marter.travel.model.Picture]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966487/error-is-no-converter-found-capable-of-converting-from-type-java-lang-string) but I'm not using `mongo`, my database is `mysql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add constructor to myModel :

```
package foo;
public class myModel {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    public myModel(String name, Integer id) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
    }
    //getter/setter
}
```

Then try this :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new foo.myModel(name, id_tr AS id) FROM ....")
```

I'm not sure about the "AS id". You may have to remove it.